# Prove Cauchy-Schwarz equality.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

My professor asked me to prove the equality in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. **The equality holds iff the vectors $v$ and $u$ are linearly dependent.**

I am able to show the equality using the fact $v$ and $u$ are linearly dependent.

But I don't know how to show the converse (i.e Showing the linear dependence using the equality).

Comment: A good start would be to look at your proof of this inequality. Given that, we can show you where to tinker a little to obtain the linear dependence from the equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\|\vec u+t\vec v\|^2 & = t^2 \|\vec v\|^2 + 2t\vec u\cdot\vec v + \|\vec u\|^2 \\[10pt]
& = at^2+bt+c.
\end{align}
This quadratic polynomial with $a>0$ is positive for every $t$ if the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ is negative, and is positive for all except one value of $t$ if the discriminant is $0$.  Express the discriminant in terms of $\|\vec u\|$, $\|\vec v\|$, and $\vec u\cdot\vec v$.

Comment: That's a nice solution. I wonder however why the discriminant has to be equal to zero? Why does the quadratic polynomial must have only one zero?

Comment: @Hendrra : The point is that it has _no_ zeros except in the case where there is some value of $t$ for which $\vec u + t\vec v$ is $\vec0,$ i.e. except where $\vec u$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec v. \qquad$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $z = pr_u (v) = \frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|u\|^2} u$  then we may write $v = z + w$, with $w \perp z$. By  Pythagoras Theorem $$\|v\|^2 = \|z\|^2 + \|w\|^2$$
Then $$\|v\| \geq \|z\|$$

And $\|v\| = \|z\| \implies\|w\| = 0$.

Comment: Notice my edit and the different appearance of the notation afterwards.  That is standard usage.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks! I didn't know that!

Answer (score 2):

The CS inequality is: $|u\cdot v|^2 \leq|u|^2 |v|^2$ .

Observe that : $\left(|u| - t|v|\right)^2 \geq 0, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$ expanding this and treat it as a quadratic function in variable $t$. This is true for all $t$ implies $\triangle \leq 0 \to$ CS inequality follows, with equality when $|u| = t|v| \to u = \pm tv \to$ linear dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that
$$
|u\cdot v|=\|u\|\,\|v\|\tag{1}
$$
This means that $u\cdot v=\pm\|u\|\,\|v\|$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\|u-tv\|^2
&=(u-tv)\cdot(u-tv)\\
&=\|u\|^2\pm2t\|u\|\,\|v\|+t^2\|v\|\\
&=(\|u\|\pm t\|v\|)^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
If $\|v\|=0$, then $u$ and $v$ are dependent (vacuously).

If $\|v\|\ne0$, then, by division, there is a $t$ so that $\|u\|\pm t\|v\|=0$. Using that $t$, $(2)$ says that $\|u-tv\|=0$, that is
$$
u=tv\tag{3}
$$
in which case $u$ and $v$ are dependent.